# xtable with latex math symbols in the table

Tags: latex, knitr, xtable, math-mode

I'm trying to write this table with checkboxes using the `xtable` package.  It would seem that the checkboxes that I've chosen are what is throwing the error.  I'm just at a loss how to fix it.

```
library(xtable)

## I want to create a table with the names of some people in two columns
nStu = 10

## Create fake names
names = character(nStu)
for(i in 1:nStu){
  names[i] = paste(LETTERS[i],rep(letters[i],5),sep='',collapse='')
}
## put check boxes behind each of the names
squares = rep('$ \\square $',nStu)

## Build the table
rosterTab = data.frame('Name'=names,'Mostly'=squares,'Sometimes'=squares, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## Now chop it in half and paste the halves together.  (Yes, if nStu is odd, this will have to be fixed)
lTab = nStu%/%2
aTab = rosterTab[1:lTab, ]
bTab = rosterTab[(lTab+1):nStu, ]
outTab = cbind(aTab,bTab)

## Everything before this point runs fine.
outTab.tab = xtable(outTab,label=FALSE)
align(outTab.tab) = 'llcc||lcc'
print(outTab.tab, include.rownames=FALSE, sanitize.text.function = function(x){x})
```

The error message that I'm getting is:

> Error in as.string(y) : Cannot coerce argument to a string

This error goes away if I use:

```
squares = rep('aaa',nStu)
```

Ideally, I want to get the names from a csv file (which I can do quite easily), and will use knitr to write this into a LaTeX document.  (I want to do this for a bunch of input files, so automating this task seems useful to me.)

Here are some other ideas that I've considered:

1. A $\LaTeX$ only solution.  Note, that there is one other difficulty (other than the squares not being in the input file), and that is that I would need to do some text manipulation on the strings in the input file.
2. Replacing the `\square` symbol with some other object that looks like a checkbox, that (through knitr) I can send to $\LaTeX$.